# How do i make list of items and amounts with an add item button that displays a new item with a button click?

Tags: java, android, button, onclick, android-edittext

I have created the start of an item/amount list with `EditText` fields but would like it so the total sits directly under the amount and for every new item/amount I add, they would sit just underneath the item/amount above them and the total would then jump down to sit under the newest amount field.

**xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.paulk.homebillcalc.HomeBills" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/monthNameTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="86dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="86dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:text="@string/month" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/monthchooser"
        android:entries="@array/months_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/monthNameTextView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/monthNameTextView"
        android:prompt="@string/months" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/PoundSign"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/itemAmountText"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/itemAmountText"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/itemAmountText"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/itemAmountText"
        android:text="@string/pound_sign"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addItemButton"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
        android:text="@string/add_item" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/itemAmountText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/monthchooser"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/addItemButton"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/addItemButton"
        android:ems="5"
        android:hint="@string/item_amount"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/PoundSign1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/totalAmountText"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/totalAmountText"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/totalAmountText"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/totalAmountText"
        android:text="@string/pound_sign"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/itemNameText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/PoundSign"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/PoundSign"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/addItemButton"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/itemAmountText"
        android:ems="8"
        android:hint="@string/item_name"
        android:inputType="text" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/totalAmountText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/itemAmountText"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/itemAmountText"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/itemAmountText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/itemAmountText"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:ems="5"
        android:hint="@string/total_amount"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Code**

```
package com.paulk.homebillcalc;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;


public class HomeBills extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener{

private final static String MONTH_OF_YEAR = "MONTH_OF_YEAR";
private final static String NAME_OF_ITEM = "NAME_OF_ITEM";
private final static String ITEM_AMOUNT = "ITEM_AMOUNT";
private final static String TOTAL = "TOTAL";

private Spinner monthChooser;

private String itemName;
private double itemAmount;
private double total;

EditText itemNameEdit;
EditText itemAmountEdit;
EditText totalEdit;

Button addField;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_bills);

    addListenerToMonthSelector();
    addListenerOnButton();

    //if new session
    if(savedInstanceState ==null){
        itemName = "";
        itemAmount = 0;
        total = 0;
    }else{
        //if its a saved session
        itemName = savedInstanceState.getString(NAME_OF_ITEM);
        itemAmount = savedInstanceState.getDouble(ITEM_AMOUNT);
        total = savedInstanceState.getDouble(TOTAL);
    }

    itemNameEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.itemNameText);
    itemAmountEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.itemAmountText);
    totalEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.totalAmountText);

    addField = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addItemButton);
    addField.setOnClickListener(this);

    itemAmountEdit.addTextChangedListener(itemAmountListener);
}

private TextWatcher itemAmountListener =  new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        try{
            itemAmount = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
        }catch(Exception e){
            itemAmount = 0;
        }
        updateTotalAmount();
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    }
};
private void updateTotalAmount() {
    //the pulls out the characters from the field, and converts the double value to a string
    double itemAmount = Double.parseDouble(itemAmountEdit.getText().toString());

    double total = itemAmount;
    totalEdit.setText(String.format("%.02f", total));

}

private void addListenerOnButton() {

    monthChooser = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.monthchooser);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home_bills, menu);
    return true;
}

public void addListenerToMonthSelector(){
    monthChooser = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.monthchooser);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v == addField){
        itemNameEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.itemNameText);
        itemAmountEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.itemAmountText);
        itemAmountEdit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: "list of items" should mean listview, doesnt it? I dont find any listview in your code. A screenshot/simple image to show what you want to create may help.

Comment: [link](http://imgur.com/aOSDfNW)<p> this is what i have so far. so each time i click the button i want a new item and amount field to display under the ones above and also for the total field to shift down to sit just under the amount field, and for this to happen every time i press the add item vutton<p>

Comment: If i understand you correctly, you need to create a list view to achieve that

Comment: but would that allow me to create a list where on the left side was the item and on the right the amount and adding a new item would create a new item/amount underneath it?

Comment: yes...using listview is a correct way to do that